# What test to use to compare within-group over time?

Tags: r, mixed-model, growth-model

I have a set of data of $\approx 13$ people. We collect their data every 2 months for 2 years.

I'm interested to see if a variable A in the data affect people's performance as well as their growth rate. So the main goal is to compare the behavior between the participants. I know I have a rather small sample size to do this but it's hard to collect longitudinal data for a bigger group. The time stamp is used to calculate their growth rate over time.

However, since overall performance is also something I want to look into, I wonder if there is any way I can combine the data to increase the power of the analysis? I only have 13 people but each of them has 12 performance data points collected at different time. What would be the best way to utilize this to compensate for the small sample size?

Comment: I don't have the reputation to leave this as a comment, altough it will not be a detailed answer. Indeed, as Rui Barrasdas said, this is a question for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). I suggest multilevel modeling / linear mixed models. Try lme4 or nlme packages in R. Good luck!

Comment: What *is* the variable A. Can you describe what it measures? What *is* the response variable? What is the goal of the analysis?  Can you post (a link to) the data? or at least, a plot? The plot should have a timeline for each of the 13 persons.